# Matplotlib figure not updating on data change

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

I'm implementing an image viewer using `matplotlib`. The idea is that changes being made to the image (such as filter application) will update automatically.

I create a Figure to show the inital image and have added a button using `pyQt` to update the data. The data *does* change, I have checked, but the Figure does not. *However*, if after I've pressed the filter application button, I *move* the image using `matplotlib`'s standard tool bar, the image is then updated.

I assume I'm doing something wrong when updating the image, but since the fact of moving it actually forces the update, it then shows the data change. I would like for this to happen when I press the button, though.

Below is some of the code. This is the initial figure initialization, which shows the original image:

```py
self.observableFig = Figure((4.0, 4.0), dpi=100)
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.observableFig)
self.canvas.setParent(self.observableWindow)
self.canvas.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
self.canvas.setFocus()

self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_click)

# Showing initial data on Window
self.observableFig.clear()
self.observableAxes = self.observableFig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
min, max = self.min, self.max
self.observableAxes.imshow(
    self.data,
    vmin=min,
    vmax=max,
    origin='lower'
)
```

And this is the event for when the button that changes the data is pressed:

```py
self.observableAxes.imshow(self.data/2, origin='lower')
#    plt.clf()
#    plt.draw()
#    plt.show()
```

I have tried `draw()`, `show()`, basically anything I've found on `pyplot` about this. I have also tried both with and without `plt.ion()` at the beginning, but it hasn't made a difference in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason that nothing is updating is that you're trying to use `pyplot` methods for a figure that's not a part of the pyplot state machine. `plt.draw()` won't draw this figure, as `plt` doesn't know the figure exists.

Use `fig.canvas.draw()` instead.

Regardless, it's better to use `fig.canvas.draw()` that `plt.draw()`, as it's clear which figure you're drawing (the former draws one, the latter draws all, but only if they're tracked by `pyplot`).

Try something along these lines:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.random((10,10))

# To make a standalone example, I'm skipping initializing the 
# `Figure` and `FigureCanvas` and using `plt.figure()` instead...
# `plt.draw()` would work for this figure, but the rest is identical.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(title='Click to update the data')
im = ax.imshow(data)

def update(event):
    im.set_data(np.random.random((10,10)))
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', update)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to know what you mean with "the latter draws all, but only if they're tracked by `pyplot`" though... is there a way I can actually add figures to be "tracked" by `pyplot`? I imagine this could be useful when wanting to refresh many figures

Comment: @Fran - By "tracked by pyplot", I basically mean "created using `plt.figure()` or `plt.subplots()`.  It sounds like you're embedding matplotlib in a gui framework of some sort?  If so, you _don't_ want things tracked by pyplot in that sense.  Otherwise, they'll have their own gui windows.  If you're not writing a separate gui application, though, then it's best to create figures using pyplot for exactly the reason you just mentioned.