# python (pandas?) live plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, live

I have been trying to get an updated plot from a pandas dataframe without success. My problem: the plot window does not appear (it is not hidden - I am sure about that).

I already tried to rebuild and change different solutions from stackoverflow. My most recent try is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880358/matplotlib-figure-not-updating-on-data-change). Pure copy,paste does work, so the problem needs to be in my modifications.

I changed it to this as I want to update it automatically every second.

```
import serial as s
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep

data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((10,10))) # I want to use pandas because 
# of easier timestamp handling   

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(title='title')
im = ax.imshow(data)

while True:
    im.set_data(np.random.random((10,10)))
    print "hello" #just to see if sth happens
    fig.canvas.draw()
    sleep(1)

plt.show()
```

Just to explain: Later I want to read data from serial ports and feed them to the plot to get my data visualized.

Well, what you expect: the provided code does print hello each second but does not show me any plot. Any ideas? I am out of them.

By the way: I am surprised that there is no "easy, straight forward" solution for this kind of problem to be found. I can imagine, there is some people who are trying to do updated plots?!

Comment: You never get out of `while True` so your code never reaches `show` part.

Comment: Have you checked this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib or https://www.lebsanft.org/?p=48 ?

Comment: @Lafexlos:True, the plt.show() is somewhat redundant, but fig.canvas.draw() is supposed to show the plot. And I checked both of your proposed links but did not get the result I was aiming for.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the package **drawnow**

```
from pylab import * # import matplotlib before drawnow
from drawnow import drawnow, figure
from time import sleep
import numpy as np

def draw_fig_real():
    imshow(data, interpolation='nearest')

data = np.random.random((10,10))

figure()
for i in range(10):
    data = np.random.random((10,10))
    sleep(0.5)
    drawnow(draw_fig_real)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: haven't given it much more than a quick try but it looks promising!